# Android: Google play music

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

Regarding thumbs icon, when i play a song I press thumbs up icon nothing happens, but when I press thumbs down icon the song restarts. why this happens?

Comment: Thumbs down means jump to the next song. If there is only one in the playlist, then I guess it rotates over it.

Comment: then thumbs up for what purpose..

Comment: There is a "Thumbs up" playlist in the playlists section.